# É possível ocultar a barra de link apresentada no canto inferior dos navegadores?

Tags: javascript, link

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de ocultar a barra de link apresentada no canto inferior esquerdo (ou direito conforme a posição do link) do navegador. É possível?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Imagem de exemplo:

[image]

Comment: Não é possível fazer isto.

Comment: @qmechanik é possível sim fazer isto. O próprio [Stack Overflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) utiliza isso no "banner" de boas-vindas. Se você passar o mouse sobre qualquer um dos icons da secção `Veja como funciona` no banner da **Central de ajuda**, você irá ver que esta barra de link não aparece. Você pode também ver um exemplo disso na minha [resposta abaixo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69181/11886).

Comment: @Chun Boa resposta a tua. Interpretei a pergunta no sentido de desativar o recurso do navegador, acho que isso não deve ser possível como mencionado pelo Victor Stafusa por razões de segurança.

Comment: Olá!
Pode esconder sim!
Vejam aí a resposta: http://allinworld99.blogspot.pt/2015/02/hide-url-hover-over-link-hide-link-from.html Testei e funciona!

Answer (score 2):

Essa barra de link existe como um recurso de segurança e foi inventada para mitigar problemas decorrentes de *phishing*. Se ela pudesse ser ocultada ou desativada, então todos os sites que promovem *phishing* iriam desativá-la, e como resultado tal recurso perderia o sentido de existir. Por essa razão, esta barra foi projetada de forma a não poder ser removida e nem desativada, não havendo portanto meio de ocultá-la.

Comment: Acho que essa informação é errônea pois acredito que ele se refere a barra de status do browser. É possível ocultar sim a status bar.

Comment: Eu não diria que está errado, nos navegadores modernos uma tag `a` com o atributo `href` sempre vai exibir o endereço, geralmente no canto inferior esquerdo da página, quando se coloca o mouse em cima do mesmo. Para não aparecer só usando alguma outra tag ou não usando o atributo `href`, porém seria necessário usar `javascript` para isso, o que faz com que isto não seja muito prático.

Answer (score 2):

Isto não é possível ser feito apenas usando puro HTML, mas sim isto é possível ser feito usando JavaScript da seguinte maneira:

```html
<span id="anchorID" >Ir para a página</span>
```

```js
$("#anchorID").click(function() {
    window.open(
    'http://www.google.com',
    '_blank' // <- Isto faz o link ser aberto numa nova janela.
    );
});
```

```css
#anchorID{cursor:pointer;}
```

Eis um exemplo online no jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fummw6wp/1